# Quest 3 device technical feasibility

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-editor

How meta Quest 3 device technical feasibility can be used to measure the following between two products?

Distance between Virtual-Virtual object & to Virtual-Real objects?

Physical interconnecting Virtual space between two objects and real-virtual objects?

can someone please explain the technicality and how to achieve this?

I need more indepth technical details